# Symetric Voltage source from OpAmp-Potenciometer circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, buffer, voltage-source

I need to design a +/- 4.5 symetric source using only a opamp buffer, a 9V battery and a potentiometer. How can i do it?

Comment: Start with realizing that voltages are always relative.

Comment: A 9 V battery's intended purpose probably includes, roughly, the typical output current compliance of many opamps. So it's a good marriage, so to speak. Is there a particular reason why you feel you need a bipolar supply and a ground reference instead of simply using a single power supply for your circuit? What are you trying to achieve? It's possible it can be done with a lot less work than what it takes to create a decent and solid virtual ground reference that can both sink and source current from either bipolar rail. In short, talk with us some more.

Comment: There exist low current ICs for the purpose. But an active, discrete sink/source ground requires a fair bit of work if you need lots of bandwidth and down to DC operation.

Comment: Consider how you might do this using only the potentiometer, then add an op-amp buffer to improve it.  Sorry but we cannot do all of your home work for you.

Answer (score -1):

Why not use two resistors instead of a potentiometer? it is possible if you use a rail-to-rail opamp and low positive and negative supply currents.

Comment: This looks more like a comment than an answer. Furthermore, the OP clearly stated that the do not have a "negative supply".